# Vue async component callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, vuejs2

```
<template>
    <div>
        <AsyncComponent1></AsyncComponent1>
        <!-- Render AsyncComponent2 after AsyncComponent1 -->
        <AsyncComponent2></AsyncComponent2>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "My Component"
    components: {
        AsyncComponent1: () => import("./AsyncComponent1"),
        AsyncComponent2: () => import("./AsyncComponent2")
    }
};
</script>
```

I'm loading two components asynchronously within a component but I need one of the components to render after the other. I wonder if thats possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `v-if` to a `ref` in the other component.

```
<template>
   <div>
       <AsyncComponent1 ref="c1"></AsyncComponent1>
       <!-- Render AsyncComponent2 after AsyncComponent1 -->
       <AsyncComponent2 v-if="$refs.c1"></AsyncComponent2>
   </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have the first component emit an event, that is listened to by the parent and used to toggle the second component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <AsyncComponent1 v-on:loaded="componentLoaded"></AsyncComponent1>
        <!-- Render AsyncComponent2 after AsyncComponent1 -->
        <AsyncComponent2 v-if="hasComponent"></AsyncComponent2>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "My Component",
    components: {
        AsyncComponent1: () => import("./AsyncComponent1"),
        AsyncComponent2: () => import("./AsyncComponent2")
    },
    data: {
        hasComponent: false
    },
    methods: {
        componentLoaded() {
            this.hasComponent = true;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

And then in AsyncComponent1.vue:

```
...
mounted() {
    this.$emit("loaded");
}
...
```